# Obtener todos los valores de un array de JSON por separado en JS

Tags: javascript, json, array, nodejs

estoy buscando la manera de poder coger todos los datos de un array JSON y mostrarlos por separado, algo así como:

```
{
  "array": [
    "apple",
    "orange"
  ]
}
```

"Apple"  "orange" por separado. Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, añade lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento y el resultado esperado, de otra manera tu publicación está incompleta y podría terminar cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utlizar un for para recorrer el objeto. [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const array1 = {"array": ["apple","orange"]};

for (var key in array1.array) {
    console.log(array1.array[key]);
}
```

Comment: Esta me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias!